# How to filter the list property's length is `0`?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a `ListAPIView`, this is the result by access the url `localhost:8000/api/physicalserver_task/list`:

```
{
    "count": 1,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 16,
            "physicalservers": [],
            ...
```

the code is bellow:

```
class PhysicalServerTaskListForHomeWorkPanelAPIView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = PhysicalServerTaskListForHomeWorkPanelSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]
    pagination_class = CommonPagination

    def get_queryset(self):
        filters = {'{}__contains'.format(key): value
               for key, value in query_params.items()}
        return PhysicalServerTask.objects.filter(**filters)
```

I have a requirement, that is filter the `physicalservers`'s length is `0`.

you know if we just filter the `id`, we can use

```
localhost:8000/api/physicalserver_task/list/?id=16
```

But how about if I want to filter the `physicalservers`'s count is `0`?

---

**EDIT-1**

My Serialiazer code is bellow:

```
class PhysicalServerTaskListForHomeWorkPanelSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    physicalservers = PhysicalServerTaskSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    physicalserver_count = serializers.IntegerField(write_only=True, allow_null=True)

    class Meta:
        model = PhysicalServerTask
        fields = "__all__"
        depth = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `phisicalservers__isnull` lookup for this:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    filters = {'{}__contains'.format(key): value
           for key, value in query_params.items()}
    if query_params.get('serverscount') == 0:
        filters.update({'phisicalservers__isnull': True})
    return PhysicalServerTask.objects.filter(**filters)
```

Comment: in Python does the None is null?

Comment: @qg_java_17137 yes in python None is analogue of null. But in this query `__isnull` lookup also match empty relation set.